# Not an entity error for classes in different databases

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, specifications

I work on a spring boot project which works on different DBs.
Today I tried to fetch some filtered records via `Specification`.
Filtering is based on a different entity on another DB with no mapping or relation.
I got a `Not an entity` error while fetching records. I thought the reason was based on the databases, so I tried the same way on two classes in the same DB and it worked.

My code is like that:

class 1:

```
@Data
@Entity
@Table(name="s")
public class S {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="id")
    Integer id;

    @Column(name="s_id")
    Integer sId;

    @Column(name="c_id")
    Integer cId;
}
```

class 2:

```
@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "c")
public class C {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Integer id;

    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;
}
```

Specificatin class:

```
public class SSpecification {

    public static Specification<S> isNameLike(String nameQuery) {
        return (root, query, builder) -> {

            query.distinct(true);

            Root<C> cRoot = query.from(Co.class);

            List<Predicate> predicateList = new ArrayList<>();
            predicateList.add(builder.equal(root.get("cId"), cRoot .get("id")));
            predicateList.add(builder.like(cRoot .get("name"), "%" + nameQuery + "%"));

            return builder.and(predicateList.toArray(Predicate[]::new));
        };
    }

    public static Specification<S> isMember(Boolean isMember) {
        return (root, query, criteriaBuilder) -> criteriaBuilder.equal(root.get("isMember"), isMember);
    }
}
```

Do you have any idea to solve this problem?

Ps, I thought chained Tx management could be a solution but I was wrong.

Comment: You cannot create a query that covers multiple database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do queries across databases with JPA except when your database presents them as if they are in the same database. You can do that for example with [Oracle database links](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18283_01/server.112/e17120/ds_concepts002.htm). I expect the other big commercial databases to have similar features.

Without such a database feature you can only query data from one database at a time.